# On piano, can one tell aurally whether a slur is written or not?

Tags: piano, technique, articulation

If you hear a piece on the piano, can you objectively tell where the slurs are written? Sometimes it feels hard to tell the difference when there are slurs or not written in a passage. Is there an objective rule you are suppose to follow when playing them other than 'play smoothly'?

Comment: The primary action of playing a slur (legato) on piano is to hold the previous note in the slur until after you’ve played the next note.

Comment: Are you asking if you can *hear* a slur in a piano piece, or if you can distinguish between a slur specified in the music and one added by the player despite the lack of a written slur. (In the first case, yes, or what would be the point of writing slurs? In the second case, no, unless you are staring at the written music while listening.)

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is "no", one can't tell by ear if a slur is written or not. There are a variety of reason for this, but here are four:

1. Often, legato is assumed, even if no marking is given. This could be based on the style of music, or it could be purely up to the player's interpretation.
2. When pedal is used, it can create a legato effect even if no slur is present, and even if the pianist is not using a legato articulation. Sometimes a passage will even be marked both staccato and to be played with pedal. To many listeners, this will not be differentiable from legato even though the pianist is playing with a detached articulation.
3. Repeated notes on the piano are effectively impossible to play legato in the strictest sense. One has to release the keys before playing them again. So a passage marked with a slur still might not be "truly" legato (without help from the pedal).
4. On the admittedly pedantic side, the question asks about the presence of a slur mark, but that's not quite sufficient to guarantee legato, because a slur and staccato can be present at the same time. The pianist would correctly play in a slightly detached manner even though the slur mark is present.

#### Examples

**(1)** Bach's Prelude in C Major (BWV 846) is written without slurs, but it is near universally played legato. Pianists with often add pedal to give the sound added richness and enhance the legato, but here is a harpsichord recording, which is clearly played legato and without any use of pedal (because the harpsichord didn't have a sustain pedal).<sup>1</sup>

[image: Holograph of BWV 846, Prelude, mm. 1–3]

**(2)** Rachmaninoff's Prelude in D minor (Op. 33, No. 4) is, by convention, played with pedal more or less throughout. However, this can contradict the staccato marking that also appear throughout. In mm. 32, for example, the right hand is clearly marked staccato — beat 4, in particular — but in the performance linked below, it sounds legato because of the use of the pedal. (The staccato is detectable with careful listening and, perhaps, some ear training.)<sup>2</sup>

[image: Rachmaninoff Op. 33, No. 4, m. 32]

(3) – (4) in progress ...

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>Video: Siebe Henstra for the Netherlands Bach Society. Image: [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Das_wohltemperierte_Klavier_I,_BWV_846-869_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian)), Holograph Manuscript 1722–23. I have a copy of the score edition being used in the video, and there are no given slurs.</sub>

<sup>2.</sup> <sub>Video: Alexander Kobrin. Image: [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Etudes-tableaux,_Op.33_(Rachmaninoff,_Sergei)), Pavel Lamm 1970 edition. This measure is also discussed in [Playing legato while staccato in Rachmaninoff's "Etude-Tableaux Op. 33"](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/104037/playing-legato-while-staccato-in-rachmaninoffs-etude-tableaux-op-33/104042#104042) and is noteworthy here because the inner voice, which is explicitly marked with a slur (or phrase mark, if one prefers) is played detached by necessity, but sounds legato via the pedaling.</sub>

Comment: Nice answer. Another possibly useful example is the 1st movement of Beethoven's Moonlight sonata, which has slurs even though it is supposed to be "without dampers" (more reasonable on the piano of Beethoven's day than on a modern piano, but modern players still use the damper pedal liberally). On the Bach, I have indeed heard it played staccato, which gives an interesting contrast between the sustained left hand notes and the detached notes in the right, but I prefer it at the same tempo most use for the 2nd prelude, at which speed it is more difficult to distinguish detached from slurred.

Answer (score 2):

@It's HEDLEY (who later renamed to Aaron) has good points in his answer, but mainly focusing on those situations where you can not hear the slurs. Here are some other points:

Sometimes a slur indicates a phrase. It can be a short or a long phrase. Then at the end of the slur you might play it like a singer which means like take a breath. That means there is a break, often a fraction of a second. You can clearly hear it. This kind of prhrasing often feels very nice. You can also play this kind if phrasing even if there is no slurs. But the slurs can be an indication regarding which kind of phrasing the composer wants.

Other times the slurs can be just a few notes that should be played legato with the last note shortend, staccato or a kind of a soft staccato depending on tempo or style. An example: It could be a series of eight notes with just two eight notes slurred at a time. You can easily hear it if the second one is shortened.

But there can also be slurs that you don't hear, simply because the player just plays legato with no speciel indications at the end of the slurs and the music feels right played that way.

How you play the slurs in a piece can be a matter of interpretation. It can also be a matter of tradition and style.

On other instruments, like wind instruments and strings there are various techniques and articulations related to slurs that of course are different from what you can do on a piano.

All in all you could say that the slurs give some extra inspiration to the performer besides which notes to play alongside what else is written like dynamics, articulations and tempo.

Answer (score 1):

You can hear phrasing and infer notation from it.   Possibly the clues are more an accented first note and a shortened last one than any special articulation of the notes within the phrase.